# Spring - @Value annotation not working when using context.getBean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Here is my app config

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${sample.config.application-resources-encoding}")
    private String sMessageSourceEncoding_;

    public WebMvcConfig() {
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        bean.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        bean.setDefaultEncoding(sMessageSourceEncoding_);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Here is where I use `context.getBean`

```
public class Message {
    
    private MessageSource ms;

    public Message() {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(WebMvcConfig.class);
        ms = (MessageSource) context.getBean("messageSource");
        ((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) context).close();
    }
}
```

At first when `WebMvcConfig` is loaded, the `@Value` annotation is working fine but if I use `context.getBean`, the `@Value` annotation does not work anymore. Is there any way to make it work using `context.getBean`?

I know I can just use `@Autowired` but I'm trying to migrate a struts1 to spring and I need the `MessageSource` in new instance but I couldn't make the `@Value` annotation to work the way I want.

Comment: Don't please don't. Why are you even constructing a new context? This context doesn't have anything to do with the one that properly resolved this. Instead make `Message` a `prototype` scoped bean and just inject the `MessageSource` in the place you are using `new Message()`. Inject an `ObjectProvider<Message>` and use the `getIfAvailable` method to obtain a fresh instance when you need it.

Comment: Do you have an example code? I'm not sure how to do this.